# changing image background in button does not work

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8.1, .net-4.5

I want to toggle button's image on each click. My code looks like this:

```
private void k1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bk1 = !bk1;
    k1.Content = bk1.ToString();

    var uriString = bk1 ? @"Assets/image1.png" : @"Assets/image2.png";
    k1.Background = new ImageBrush {  
        ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(uriString, UriKind.Relative)) 
    };
}
```

When I click on the button I get the exception

> System.ArgumentException : "The given System.Uri cannot be
>   converted into a Windows.Foundation.Uri."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set build action of images to content, use proper tags for your Uri,  remove Relative URI.

```
var uriString = bk1 ? @"ms-appx:/Assets/image1.png" : @"ms-appx:/Assets/image2.png";
k1.Background = new ImageBrush { ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(uriString)) };
```

Answer (score 2):

While you are preparing a URI from local assets you should use ms-appx.
Use the below code

```
var uriString = bk1 ? @"ms-appx:Assets/image1.png" : @"ms-appx:Assets/image2.png";
```